# A divisibility question concerning polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

What is the condition that $$x^2 + x + 1$$ is a factor of $$(x + 1)^n − x^n − 1$$.

Comment: Roots of the equation are $\omega$ and $\omega^{2}$. Try substituting them in the second equation.

Comment: I tried using your hint and I'm getting that the required condition is n should be odd and not a multiple of 3.

Comment: You can edit your post with your results and let us see what you did :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the residues are cyclic with period 6 and that for $n=6k+1$ or $n=6k+5$, then  $x^2+x+1$ is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$ be a primitive third root of unity. Then its minimal polynomial, $x^2+x+1$, divides $$ p(x)=(x+1)^n-x^n-1 $$
iff $p(\omega)=0$. Since $\omega+1=-\omega^2$ is a primitive sixth root of unity, that happens if:
$$ (-1)^n \omega^{2n}-\omega^n-1 = ((-1)^n+1)\,\omega^{2n}-3\cdot\mathbb{1}_{n\equiv 0\pmod{3}}=0, $$
that is if $n$ is odd and not a multiple of three, or $n\equiv\{1,5\}\pmod{6}$.

Comment: Nice one.  My proof (which I did not put in my answer) involves the fact that $(x+1)^6 - 1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^4+5x^3+9x^2+6x)$ which is not nearly as clean as the key point in your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^3-1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ and $(x+1)^3+1=(x+2)(x^2+x+1)$. It follows that the result depends only on the remainder of $n$ modulo$~6$. Moreover, for $n=0,1,\ldots,5$ the remainders of $(x+1)^n$ and $x^n$ modulo$~x^2+x+1$ are $$1,x+1,x,-1,-x-1,-x\quad \text{respectively}\quad 1,x,x^2,1,x,x^2.$$
Taking differences we see that $n\equiv 1,5\pmod6$ are solutions.